# Giving permission in WPF tab

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, event-handling, tabcontrol

My WPF program (c#)has 5 tabs and a login screen(the users are in db in sql server).
One of the tabs has 5 rectangle and I need that only two of the 3 users I defined can do an event I programed that changes the color of a rectangle.
How can I program it so that one of the users wont have the permission to do the event?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is, after login, you fetch from the database the permissions granted to the logged user. After that:

1. hide parts of the GUI the logged user is not authorized to see or interact with. This will avoid the user to initiate actions he cannot complete (and you would have to stop later), or
2. handle differents outcomes based on granted permissions. E.g. a "standard" user can see only the records he created, an "administrator" could see all the records from all users.

Comment: How can i do it in c#?